# Deterministic sort of two different objects with the same hash code

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Let's say I have two different objects of the same (arbitrary) type passed to a generic function. I need a way to order them the same way each time, no matter which order they are passed in as arguments. Their order is not important, just that is consistent in the edge case that they have the same hash code, but do not pass .equal. In the majority case, in which they have different hashcodes, the hashcodes will simply be used.

Assumptions:

- Same base type
- Same hash code
- Not same object
- Reference type
- Objects cannot be pinned
- .Equals returns false
- object.ReferencesEquals returns false
- neither object is null
- the order only need to be consistent within the particular runtime of the particular assembly

Hopefully, someone can come up with a creative solution to this, rare, but troublesome edge case that I have missed. Thanks

Comment: You could try sorting on their memory address, although this would only be consistent during the same session of running your app. Once you restart the app, the addresses will change. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbcf4ta.aspx

Comment: @Mangist "Objects cannot be pinned"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define an equality comparer that works purely on identity:

```
private static ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T:class
{
    public bool Equals(object x, object y) => ReferenceEquals(x, y);

    public int GetHashCode(object obj) => RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
}
```

Then (ideally as a last resort, having tried other possible means), add the elements into a `Dictionary<T, int>` that has that as its comparer, with the objects as as the keys, and an incrementing number as the value.

That value becomes your tie-breaker, guaranteed to assert the same order each time.

Comment: You cannot sort using an `IEqualityComparer`.  You need an `IComparer`.

Comment: @Servy the interface is largely irrelevant

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer The interface is *hugely* relevant.  One accomplishes what you're asking, and one doesn't.

Comment: @Servy I mean for my particular use. Sorry for my terse wording

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Your question specifically states that you need to put items into a total order, not just determine whether two items are equal.  Those are radically different needs.  One of the interfaces allows you to accomplish it, and one doesn't.  If you don't actually need a total order of your items, and instead only need to be able to determine whether any two items are the same item, then you need to make some pretty radical changes to your question, because right now you state that *you can already compare for equality* and you need to get an order from that.

Comment: @Servy my apologies for not being more clear. For my particular use, I do not need any particular interface implemented, this will only be used in one function of one class.

Comment: @Jon Hanna just curious is RuntimeHelpers.GetHashcode do something different than just calling the objects.GetHashcode methods? If so, any idea what it uses?

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer To perform a sort you're going to need a comparer, unless you have some compelling need to re-implement a sorting algorithm instead of simply using a sorting algorithm from the framework.  Why do you feel the need to re-implement your own sorting algorithm, instead of using a framework's implementation of a common sort?

Comment: @Servy I am not doing a general sort, I just need to order TWO objects, feel free to edit Jon's answer or create your own that you deem to be more correct. Thanks for your insight

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer And apparently you feel confident in being able to do that given a method that tells you whether the two are references to the same object, rather than a method that tells you whether the first object is less than, greater than, or equal to the second object.  I have no idea how you plan to do it, but apparently it's irrelevant to you which you get.

Comment: @Servy your insight is valuable as it may be more generally applicable; however, for my particular use it is irrelevant as I will just be copying the code withing the method and not making a dedicated class. With that said, you making an edit or a more correct answer that is more useful to more people might be most valuable to SO. Your comments will be seen by less people looking up the same problem

Comment: @Servy who said anything about sorting by IEqualityComparer?

Comment: "is RuntimeHelpers.GetHashcode do something different than just calling the objects.GetHashcode" Yes, it calls the default object GetHashCode even if it was overridden. This also means that it would itself be worth a look for arbitrary ordering, before trying the above, which as said is a tie-breaker of last resort since it costs memory and time.